# How to set device's display Height to View

Tags: xml, android-layout

I'm trying to set CameraKitView to match the screen size in a ScrollView in a LinearLayout.

I got my ScreenSize call within my onCreate method in my MainActivity:
int ScreenSizeHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

Is there a way to get it as the height of the CameraView within my xml.

```
<com.camerakit.CameraKitView
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="ScreenSizeHeight" <----- HELP
            app:camera_facing="back" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below line to get your device's display height

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int displayHeight = display.getHeight();
```

Through the *displayHeight*, you can set `CameraKitView` height programmatically.

**For Instance**,

```
CameraKitView cameraKitView= findViewById(R.id.camera);
cameraKitView.setHeight(displayHeight);
```

Comment: I tried to add it to my onCreate but it says it Cannot resolve method 'setHeight'

Comment: I've come so far that:

abstract class CameraPreview extends ViewGroup

and not on view.

Any thoughts on how I might do it with viewGroup?